# Don't get to put the third data set in the histogram with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

Hi guys I have this code:

```
labels = 'ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY'
uniparc = uniparc
uniref = uniref
Sprot = Sprot

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, uniparc, width, label='Uniparc_data')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, uniref, width, label='Uniref_data')
rects3 = ax.bar(x + width/2, Sprot, width, label='Sprot_data')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Amino acids frequency')
ax.set_title('Frequency of Amono acids in Uniprot databank')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()
plt.savefig('AminoAcidUniprotDistributuion.pdf');
```

And I got this result:

[image]

But I would like to have the third data in that pic. I try to find some stuff to correct the code but I have no more time to look for.

Any of you can help me to solve this problem?

Thank you very much for your time.

Paulo

```
uniparc = [0.09257386770949864,
 0.012313832615522758,
 0.0548112553175077,
 0.06160947411180779,
 0.038222501797905525,
 0.07389678523368833,
 0.022170302961684787,
 0.05448853409802474,
 0.048580830921506696,
 0.09896074415277979,
 0.022859889896487295,
 0.03815257876469618,
 0.04970337254332669,
 0.03887664392804586,
 0.058266931851542164,
 0.06761364192952851,
 0.05578811712996716,
 0.06863734713196595,
 0.012985224582591685,
 0.02860004505547911]

uniref = [0.06935098720335207,
 0.008916136410877625,
 0.04090342462890086,
 0.04593917569977177,
 0.02840841609182606,
 0.05465903652568739,
 0.01644025555468207,
 0.04056766419227444,
 0.035849782564443856,
 0.07371567236397218,
 0.017025828199349453,
 0.027997309395520704,
 0.036762585661199325,
 0.02872114107868124,
 0.04330190684063798,
 0.04973320060758974,
 0.04130568933390208,
 0.051281264373134405,
 0.009649463942347296,
 0.021255432248355927]

Sprot = [0.00015635595579483537,
 2.6180027693988223e-05,
 0.00010341666145829634,
 0.00012744959933426033,
 7.31873037059761e-05,
 0.00013406307800210577,
 4.3089542174271394e-05,
 0.00011212654102955857,
 0.000110082778614388,
 0.0001827897748610178,
 4.572355675447346e-05,
 7.68798149236662e-05,
 8.966488452282442e-05,
 7.445030874357882e-05,
 0.00010477071533400868,
 0.000125561418519232,
 0.00010139156995989686,
 0.00012995720093529988,
 2.0801641418090706e-05,
 5.5288539944181214e-05]
```

Maybe because of the lower values in the last data set?

Comment: You have a typo: rects3 = `ax.bar(x, + width/2, Sprot, width, label='Sprot_data')` There is a comma after `x`. You probably want to remove that.

Comment: Hi  bernie I remove the comma but still not get the data in the figure. 8(  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the third bar plot is too small to percieve unless you enlarge the image.

Apart from that, though, your widths should be adjusted a bit like this:

```
width = 0.3
# ...
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width, uniparc, width, label='Uniparc_data')
rects2 = ax.bar(x, uniref, width, label='Uniref_data')
rects3 = ax.bar(x + width, Sprot, width, label='Sprot_data')
```